# Select random option from dropdown in cypress

Tags: typescript, random, drop-down-menu, cypress

I run a script and want to select the random option on every run.

```
it('random_option' () => {
    cy.visit(url)
    const count = $options;
    const random_option = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
    cy.get('selector').select(random_option);
})
```

Comment: Isn't that TypeScript? why there is a type? and what is your question exactly?

Comment: yes, it is a typescript and I want to run in nodejs in which i am running the dropdown random option on every run.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the length of options within the select then use that value to generate random index.

```js
cy.get(".select-selector")
  .find(".option")
  .its("length")
  .then((optionsLength) => {
    const random_option = Math.floor(Math.random() * optionsLength);
    cy.get(".select-selector").select(random_option);
  });
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/selectRandomOption.md).

Comment: thanks for the help but i  need something else in which i just write a cmnd and on running it's auto select the menu option every time.

Comment: well that would make it less code. What is the html for the auto select?

Comment: Please check this: hope you get my point

Comment: <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span><select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" data-bv-field="state">
                                    <option value=" ">Please select your state</option>
                                    <option>Alabama</option>
                                    <option>Wyoming</option>
                                 </select>